# Samples that will result in a large p-value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-significance, p-value

> Consider a one-sample t-test regarding the population mean time to
>   complete a task with a one-sided alternative hypothesis of Ha: μ < 10
>   minutes.  A random sample of times to complete the task will be
>   obtained as part of a study.  Which of the following values of the
>   sample mean times would result in a p-value of more than 0.5?

1. 7 minutes
2. 9 minutes
3. 11 minutes
4. 13 minutes

I chose 3 and 4 since their values will skew the data towards rejecting the alternative hypothesis.  Is this correct?  Also, would it be correct to say that "the p-value is the probability that the null hypothesis is true?" (as to interpret it in some vague sense?)

Answer (score 2):

> "*will skew the data towards rejecting the alternative hypothesis*"

-- you *don't* 'reject the alternative'. You either reject the null or you fail to do so.

> would it be correct to say that "the p-value is the probability that the null hypothesis is true?"

No. It's *the probability that a sample result at least as extreme as the one observed will occur, given that $H_0$ is true*.

Answer (score 0):

3 and 4 is correct for the reasons you mentioned.

However, your interpretation of the p-value is not correct. It is very loosely linked to the probability of H0.

See the wikipedia article on p-value.

> In statistical hypothesis testing the p-value is the probability of
>   obtaining a test statistic at least as extreme as the one that was
>   actually observed, assuming that the null hypothesis is true.

And from  Hubbard, R.; Lindsay, R. M.  (article in citations on the wiki):

> Using a Bayesian significance test for a normal mean, James Berger and
>   Thomas Sellke (1987, pp. 112–113) showed that for p values of .05,
>   .01, and .001, respectively, the posterior probabilities of the null,
>   Pr(H0 | x), for n = 50 are .52, .22, and .034. For n = 100 the
>   corresponding figures are .60, .27, and .045. Clearly these
>   discrepancies between p and Pr(H0 | x) are pronounced, and cast
>   serious doubt on the use of p values as reasonable measures of
>   evidence. In fact, Berger and Sellke (1987) demonstrated that data
>   yielding a  p value of .05 in testing a normal mean nevertheless
>   resulted in a posterior probability of the null hypothesis of at least
>   .30 for any objective (symmetric priors with equal prior weight given
>   to H0 and HA ) prior distribution.